# Filling a css grid with images after clicking on a button and changing to a different web page via jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-grid

I am trying to display images in a CSS grid, but depending on which button is pressed I want specific images to be displayed and a specific amount of boxes in the grid.

I have written some code in jQuery that loads the html file and then is supposed to execute code to display the grid, but it seems like the code doesn't execute, there are no errors in the console.

```
$(".il2").click(function() {
    window.location.assign("filepath/page.html");

    for (var i = 0; i < menArray.length; i++) {
        $("<img class='pBox' src='' alt='products'></img>").appendTo(".productGrid");
    }
    $(".pBox").attr("src", "assets/grid-button-image.png");
})
```

Comment: Hi, please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where is `menArray` defined?

Comment: menArray is defined just above as var menArray = [" ", " ", " "]